# What is "immaculate English"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

A row has broken out in London over a restaurant which stipulated in an advertisement for waiters that they should be able to speak "immaculate English".

Allegations ensued that this was a cover for excluding recent immigrants.

But on a different tack there is a letter in today's Observer asking *Who speaks immaculately*? The Oxford Dictionary on-line defines *immaculate* as *perfectly clean, neat or tidy* - as in "an immaculate white suit".

A number of questions arise. What is meant by *immaculate English*? Does Donald Trump, or Sadiq Khan, the new Mayor of London speak *immaculate English*?  And what might have been a better term to use to describe the sort of English that would be desirable in a waiter?

But the most important question of all is whether the use of the term *immaculate* is in fact a euphemism for excluding people on a racist basis? Is it?

Comment: It might be intended to mean "no foreigners" but there is nothing specifically about "immaculate" meaning pure in English

Comment: My non-online Oxford Compact Dictionary gives a third meaning for immaculate of 'without fault'. Only the person who drafted the ad knows exactly what the intent was, but I think it is as likely, if it is a 'fine dining' establishment that they would be trying to rule out candidates who were not willing or able to speak without excessive idiom. In other words, it is as likely to be about class as about immigration status, innit?

Comment: @Spagirl *Immaculate* would be an odd word to use to describe the speech of someone who spoke using the received pronunciation - and it would be very unusual nowadays for anyone to object to employing a waiter with a regional/working-class accent.

Comment: @WS2 You are talking about accents and pronunciation, I was meaning speech patterns, register and use of idiom, which is not the same thing at all. Sorry if I wasn't clear. Its the difference between 'May I take your order' and 'hands up for the fish.' :D

Comment: @Spagirl It is difficult to comment much further on this as I can't find the original advert on line, and am not clear as to what type of restaurant it was.

Answer (score 5):

It's a figurative use.  *Immaculate* means spotless, perfectly clean, without blemish or stain, so *immaculate English* means the language spoken without the "stain" of ungrammatical or improper usage.

The phrase has an in-built fallacy, namely that there is some standard by which it's possible to judge "perfect" (or "spotless", if you prefer) English.  There isn't.

The kind of English I would find desirable in a waiter is fluent, vernacular English.  I would also prefer that my waiter not introduce himself by name, tell me that he'll "be taking care of me", or respond to my order by saying, "Awesome!"  But that's just me.

If you want to know whether the term *immaculate* is a euphemism, you'll have to ask the restaurant owner.  People suspect an ulterior motive for two reasons:

1. Good waiters have been speaking less-than-perfect English for years.  If you're really worried about the service at your restaurant, why would you impose an unnecessary requirement?
2. The diction, usage, and accent of recent immigrants has long been a common basis for derision and exclusion.

Comment: I like your answer. I particularly agree with the paragraph which starts with *The kind of English...*. And to add to those things which I would prefer a waiter didn't say would be *today* - used in the sense of *What can I get you today?* - as if I visit the place 365 days in the year.

Comment: Lately they always seem to respond to my orders with “Perfect!”—though that is a tense formation that I seldom use in placing my order.